# how to fix wierd intellisense coloring ( VS 2019 )

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I just upgraded to visual studio 2019 from 2017 and a lot of colors changed in the formatting.
I have been changing it back to the old colors but there's something wierd that I don't know how to fix.

calling methods show the method with a diffrent color depending on the parameters, and I want them both to show the same color.

Example:

```
    public void method( int  t){
     
    }
     
    public int a;
    public vector3Int v;
     
    ///////
     
    method( a); /// method shows as teal color
    method(v.z); /// method shows as black color
```

so the fact that I have a parameter that is an int is showing one color and when the parameter is a vector.z it shows another color, even though both are ints, obviously this is discriminating between a direct int and a int inside a struct, the question is, how do I fix this so they are both the same color?

Comment: Intellisense does not color text based on subtypes, but based on types. For it "main" type is `vector3Int` in this case, so then all parameters which variable of this type holds will be displayed with the same color. Your a and v variables are types of `int` and `struct`, they are not the same. But if you will define something like `public int vInt = v.z` - they I believe it will be displayed with the teal color.

Comment: thanks, but how can I change it to the same color on both?( i dont want to change code but the options on visual studio)

Comment: You could change color using Tools -> Fonts and Colors -> User Types; but it will not help you - because you could set color for struct, but then this color will be applied to all struct variables which you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing color on Tools -> Fonts and Colors -> User Types : Methods

Answer (score 0):

user members locals worked for me in 2022 VS

Comment: Under tools- fonts colors---

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).